# Inconsistent single large file copy speed (W2k12)

Tags: networking, network-adapter, windows-server-2012, 10gbit

The case is:

- 2 (identical) W2k12 physical blade servers,hosted on the same enclosure.
- connected via enclosure internal 10Gbe switch (Force10 MXL).
- Both servers are at the same subnet.
- Both servers have 2 NICs teamed by MS Team (Switch independent).
- NICs are configured with MTU of 9014
- Chimney Offload is disabled
- Receive side scaling also disabled
- MXL switch ports are configures with MTU of 9600.
- no other "special" configurations

Issue is:
When copying large file (<100GB), inconsistent speed is observed. - i.e. copy starts at ~500MB/s, than climbs to +1GB/s (which is great) but than it drops back down to ~500MB/s, and than climbs back to +1GB/s and cycles like that for the rest of the copy action.

any ideas?

Comment: It isn't clear whether you're asking about the difference between the two servers' performance, or why the performance varies over time.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way that Windows does the copy :

- It fills up the RAM cache with data, which it does at the speed of the source
- It writes out the RAM, at the speed of the target
- Repeating as required.

This means that your target is capable of only half the speed of the source.

You may get more consistent results by using [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/),
which is free and open source.
FastCopy does not use the Windows cache and does multiplex reads and writes
in parallel using multi-threading, which means that it can achieve speeds
that are more in line with the capabilities of the hardware.